# Make each exported file in its own folder

Tags: python, pandas

I am exporting some files and I want to export it in a 'exports' folder.

The files are `file1.shp,file2.shp,etc`

I want to save each in its own folder with the same name.
Like: `exports/file1/file1.shp` and so on.

Until now I have managed to make it save them in this manner:

exports/file1.shp with the file2.shp, etc. All scattered in the `exports` to put it simply.

How can I do it like the first example?

Code:

```
folder = path.Path(path)
d = defaultdict(list)
os.mkdir(folder+'\\'+ 'exports' ) 

with open(folder+ '\\'+'exports'+'\\'+'log.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for shpfile  in glob.iglob(folder + '/*/*/*.shp' ,recursive = True):
        try:
            df = geopandas.read_file(shpfile)
            d[os.path.basename(shpfile)].append(df)
        except FionaValueError as ex:
            if not os.listdir(shpfile): 
                fw.write(f'{shpfile} is empty' + '\n')
    for cat, lst in d.items():
        if cat.endswith('.shp'): 
            pd.concat(lst,sort = True).to_file(folder/'exports'/cat)
```